# operator overloading in c++ - A query

Tags: c++

I was reading a book on operator overloading in c++ and I encountered the following code:

```
class Array {   
    ...
    public:        
    Array & operator << ( int x) {
          // insert x at the end of the array  
    }  
};
```

Next It says: that overloading of the form  `a << x << y << z ;`
 wll not work
So It suggests that second invocation is treated as :
`( (a  << x)<< y  ) << z`  .so it recommends using **return *this**;

But I am not getting how **return *this** functions here? Please help!
Here is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Array {

 int *a;
 int capacity;
 int size;
 int incr;

 public:
    Array (int c=10) { 
        a = new int[c]; 
        capacity = c;
        for (int i=0; i<c; i++) a[i]=0;
        size=0;
        incr = c;
    }
    Array  &operator << (int x) { 
        if(size<capacity) a[size++] = x;
        else {
            int *tmp = new int [capacity+incr];
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) tmp[i]=a[i];
            delete[] a;
            a = tmp;
            a[size++]=x;
            capacity = capacity+incr;
        }
        return *this;

     };
    int operator [] (int i) { 
        if(i<size) return a[i];
    };


};



int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

 int s = atoi (argv[1]);
 Array A (s);
 for (int i=0; i<s; i++) A << i << i+1; 
 for (int i=0; i<s; i++) cout << A[i] << endl; 


}
```

Comment: Please format your code by indenting with four spaces.  See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I would take care of that in the future, thanks buddy

Comment: I think it should be `Array & operator <<` instead `void & operator <<`

Comment: Ignore that code, that is such a horrible practice anyway.

Comment: Btw the short codes were just examples so they were just meant to give an idea thats why void & is used, the last code was to actually show a working example

Comment: `void &`?? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: may be...:) but as I said its not a book but a tutorial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with operator overloading. It's called chaining and it's easier to explain using regular member functions. Suppose you defined a member function called `insert` like this:

```
Array& insert(int x) {
    // insert x at the end of the array
    return *this;
}
```

The `return *this` will return a reference to the current object so that you can chain calls like this:

```
Array a;
a.insert(0).insert(1).insert(2);
```

Which is essentially equivalent to:

```
Array a;
a.insert(0);
a.insert(1);
a.insert(2);
```

Each call to `insert()` will return a reference to the original object, allowing other calls to be made using that returned reference. You can overload the << operator to do the same thing:

```
Array& operator<<(int x) {
    // insert x at the end of the array
    return *this;
}
```

Now you can chain calls like this:

```
Array a;
a << 0 << 1 << 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting confused because of the spacing of `Array  &operator <<`.  The return value of the function is `Array&`, a reference to the array object.

Here's an example.  In your call `A << i << i+1`, the `A << i` is called first and a reference to the updated `A` is returned.  Next `A << i+1` is called, with that new reference.

Comment: so what exactly does *this do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes everything is ok with your code. `operator <<` in your semantics will and returning refference to same object which called it. You can see same in code of `operator <<` of `std::ostream` and `operator >>` of `std::istream`.